# Find doc from field having all specified words

Tags: mongodb, search

I've problem to find the good document search request do find all documents containing in their 'name' field all the specified values.

I've this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("607c1caa4b2964d0185301ff"),
    "nb" : 1,
    "name" : "mini computer 24GB"
}
```

When I run the following find request...

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"$text":{$search:'computer dummy'}})
```

... the document is returned. An OR is done but I want a AND operation. Should I use a list of $and ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found. each word must be in quotes as this:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({$text:{$search:"\"computer\"  \"24GB\""}})
```

Not really intuitive!